# Contradictory Lines - Object or Class?

Tags: python, class, object

For this example, let's just use a Person object, that has a property age :

```
>>> fab = Person(age=39)
>>> fab.age
39
```

In this case, I set up an object fab whose type is Person (a custom class).

This is kind of contradictory. First the text says person is an object then says its a class

Comment: `First the text says person is an object then says its a class` Which text? `fab` is an object of class `Person`

Comment: by text i mean text book i am referring to learn python.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) - "Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new instances of that type to be made. "

Answer (score 0):

In programming, a `Class` is a framework or blueprint for an `object`. Think of objects like an "instance" of a class. A common analogy is with cars. The class is the blueprint for the car and the objects are the constructed cars themselves.

So, `Person` alone is a reference to the class. However, when you *initialize* `Person` like so `fab = Person(age=39)`, `fab` is now an object based on the class `Person`.

[How classes and objects work](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/HLUs/User_Guide/classes/classoview.shtml)